# How do I add another css to Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a Bootstrap site and have a css (with function to show a sticky note post-it) from another project I want to implement.

When the css is loaded in the index.html, the menu in Bootstrap gets shadow effect from the sticky-css - how do I code the css to only show in  ?

### The sticky.css file:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand+SC);

.sticky.div:sn {
      margin: 0 auto;
}

.sticky h1,.sticky p{
  font-family:"Reenie Beanie","Ruthie";
  line-height: 100%;
  font-weight:normal;
}

.sticky ul,.sticky li{
  list-style:none;
}
.sticky  ul{
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:2em;
}

.sticky ul li{
  margin:1em;
  float:left;
}

.sticky ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  background:#ffc;
  display:block;
  height:12em;
  width:12em;
  padding:1em;
  -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .15s linear;
  -o-transition:-o-transform .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .15s linear;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-6deg);
}

.sticky ul li h1{
   font-family:"Reenie Beanie","Ruthie";
line-height: 90%;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
.sticky ul li p{

  font-size:90%;
}

.sticky ul li:nth-child(even) a{
  -o-transform:rotate(4deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(4deg);
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  background:#cfc;
}
.sticky ul li:nth-child(3n) a{
  -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  position:relative;
  top:-5px;
  background:#ccf;
}
.sticky ul li:nth-child(5n) a{
  -o-transform:rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(5deg);
  position:relative;
  top:-10px;
}
.sticky ul li a:hover,ul li a:focus{
  box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}
.sticky ol{text-align:center;}
.sticky ol li{display:inline;padding-right:1em;}
.sticky ol li a{color:#fff;}
```

Comment: So you want only certain properties from your css file and not all of it?

Comment: Can you show html and working code (jsfidle/plunker etc.) ? I hope your menu doesn't use the sticky class.

Comment: I just oploaded the sticky notes I want to implement. No menu just the notes 

http://jsfiddle.net/tuukkaq/e15hfqg1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a custom class to your unordered list like this:

```
<ul class="sticky-thing">
    <li><!--your sticky list items --></li>
    <li><!--your sticky list items --></li>
    <li><!--your sticky list items --></li>
    <li><!--your sticky list items --></li>
</ul>
```

And then add `.sticky-things` to all the `ul` tags in your custom css like this:

```
ul.sticky-thing li{
  margin:1em;
  float:left;
}
ul.sticky-thing li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  background:#ffc;
  display:block;
  height:14em;
  width:14em;
  padding:1em;
  -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .15s linear;
  -o-transition:-o-transform .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .15s linear;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-6deg);
}
/* other ul properties */
```

And your sticky css will be independent from the bootstrap css.

Here's a modified version of your jsfiddle with a dummy bootstrap navbar (menu) added along with the above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e15hfqg1/2/

Comment: Glad I could help :) Do mark this as the right answer by clicking the tick mark next to my answer if it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: Nice!! :) Do check out a site I co-managed Nick: http://raiot.in Some articles are not in English but some are. We are currently initiating a Living Wage/Minimum Wage campaign in Shillong too.

Comment: Thanks again I have really faught with thoose sticky notes :D I'll take a look at the site and get inspired :D

Answer (score 2):

Are you using third-party addons for bootstrap. I know of several that use the `.sticky` class, so there would certainly be a conflict there.

Can you rename your styles to something like `.sticky-note`?

Comment: Thanks - will try to rename the css :)